# IF in WHERE statement excludes too many records (Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am struggling with the IF in the WHERE statement.
My Access Query uses a parameter. The WHERE statement should only be executed if the parameter has a value, otherwise it should be ignored.
This is what I have right now:

```
PARAMETERS varMachineID Text ( 25 );
SELECT RequestNumber
FROM Requests
WHERE ( MachineID=IIf([varMachineID]<>"",[varMachineID],MachineID) );
```

This statement should work fine. However, the table can also contain records with a blank MachineID. With this WHERE statement those records are now excluded by the Query. This should not happen.
I tried an OR statement in the ELSE but then the query becomes too complex to handle.

Hope someone has a solution for me.

Thanks.

ps. This is a stripped example, the query I have contains more parameters and more conditions in the WHERE statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that "blank" means `NULL`.  If so, I think you want:

```
WHERE MachineID = varMachineID or varMachineID is NULL
```

This will select *all* records when `varMachineId` is `NULL`.  It will select only matching ones when it is not `NULL`.

Comment: Sometimes the solution can be this simple. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It is probably this you need:

```
WHERE 
    MachineID Is Null Or 
    MachineID = IIf(varMachineID = "", MachineID, varMachineID);
```